# Why do I always `unauthorized: authentication required` when using bash to connect to Azure Container Registry?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-container-registry

I'm writing a simple bash script to pull an image from Azure Container Registry. If I type the command on the shell, I get authenticated and the images are pulled without any issue. However, when I run the same commands using the bash script, I get the unauthorized error.

**Script**

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo service docker start

docker logout
az logout

docker login myregistry.azurecr.io

sudo docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/rstudio-server:0.1
```

**Error**

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/": unauthorized: aad access token with sp failed client id must be guid
Error response from daemon: Head "https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/rstudio-server/manifests/0.1": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

I don't understand why it's happening even when I'm logged in.

Comment: From this [authentication-options – Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#authentication-options)

Did you try to log in with the service principal? [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal)

Comment: I did, but I feel like that's exactly how I did in the script. If I use az login or docker login using the registry name, it works fine on the cli but not from the script. I feel like I'm missing something. Also, I do not have permission to change much on the ACR other than pushing and pulling images.

Comment: Hey, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot. [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in my environment working fine for me.

[image]

Make sure Your password will be stored unencrypted in `/root/.docker/config.json` if not try to authenticate it manually by providing username and password in bash script.

```
sudo service docker start

docker logout
az logout

docker login myregistry.azurecr.io --username $SP_APP_ID --password $SP_PASSWD

sudo docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/rstudio-server:0.1
```

You can also use the username and password of ACR as prvided in below picture inplace of APP_ID and  SP_PASSWD

[image]

Would Suggest you to please follow this [***Microsoft Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal) for more information about authentication of ACR from Docker

Comment: I'm still working on this. I did exactly what you wrote but I still get permission denied. I'm checking on the portal now but also trying to connect to IT to figure out what's happening. I'll let you know soon. Thank you for posting the solution - it is very helpful.

Comment: It still didn't work. I think it has something to do with az package on linux?? The same process works from Windows terminal.

Comment: So, turns out I needed sudo for az login and az acr login. For some reason, adding my user in visudo didn't work. I may have done something wrong in the process. I appreciate your help!
I'll still mark this as an answer because there are somethings I learnt from your post.